# How to continuously animate between two colours used as border colour in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I would like to continuously fade between two colours used as the color for the border of a container in Flutter. I already got a Tween setup and am now wondering, how I can fade back when the animation has finished and restart it. I use a Tween and an AnimationController, here is the method I use to reset the animation:

```
Future _startBorderAnimation() async {
    try {
        await _animationController
            .forward()
            .orCancel;
    } on TickerCanceled {

    }
}
```

Right now it fades from cyan to red and then jumps back to cyan without a transition. How can I turn this into a continuous animation, fading from cyan to red, red to cyan, cyan to red, etc.

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's already a repeat function in the controller just pass true in the reverse parameter to reverse the animation when it ends

```
_animationController.repeat(reverse: true);
```